# invocar a archivos de script - bash

Tags: bash, scripting

hasta ahora estaba haciendo la invocación del archivo de la forma `./c_bash.sh`
Ahora quiero hacerlo de la forma `./c_bash.sh <nombreDelFicheroDeDatos>`

El script contiene esta información:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " -- Fichero c_bash.sh --"

while IFS="," 
read v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13; 
do if [ -z "$v12" ]; 
then echo "$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,'unknown',$v13"; 
else echo "$v1, $v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,$v12,$v13"; 
fi;
done < train.csv
```

Cómo puedo hacer el cambio?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y no seria mas práctico así?  `./c_bash.sh < train.csv`.  Asi no tienes que retocar casi nada, tan solo quitar el `done < train.csv` y poner `done` a secas

Comment: De acuerdo con lo que dice, @masterguru. En cualquier caso, si quieres pasar un parámetro, pásalo con `./script.sh "nombre"` y luego lo recoges en el script con la variable `$1`. Y si pones otro parámetro estará en `$2`, etc.